# Send button using own contact form

Tags: ajax, plugin-contact-form-7, contact

I have an own contact template [here](http://schreinerei-lignum.de/contact_us) , und built it according to [this](http://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/how-to-build-your-own-wordpress-contact-form-and-why/) info.

The submit button does not work because another event seems to block the reload of page.
Looking in the console, I see an xml http post request which I do not want.
Can you help to find the js code that blocks the reload.
Should I post the header.php or the page-contact-us.php?
Contact form 7 is installed, do I have to drop the plugin?

I used contact form 7, but would like to change the required property of a field dynamically: if the checkbox is clicked, the address fields should change from non-required to required. This can be done with php, but I dont know how to change the php code of cf7

Comment: The article you linked seems to be suggesting this option as an alternative to a plugin. Do you still need Contact Form 7? I suggest you first try to deactivate that plugin and see if your form works then.

Comment: why did you downvote, it is not easy to find out that i have to deactivate cf7. Yes, my own contact form is an alternative to 7, so thanks, works now.

Comment: It wasn't me who downvoted for the record. If my suggestion worked for you, will you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't need to use Contact Form 7 (as you are creating your own custom contact form), deactivate the plugin to solve the conflict.

Comment: What to do if I still need cf 7, and also want to use my own template?

Comment: Without seeing exactly what you've done, it's hard to know. I'd start by checking in Firebug or similar what's happening on the page. If you've used CF7 CSS selectors to style your form, this could be affecting what happens when the user submits.